# Where do MSDS data sheets get their information? (How to write one)

Tags: safety

For example looking at Sigma-Aldrich MSDS sheets, where do they cite their studies that found hazard in the chemicals? Or in other words, how does one "write" an MSDS sheet? I need to write one for a solution that I designed but I don't know how I should approach writing it other than just combining MSDS data on the components of the solution individually. Thanks

Comment: Industrial Hygiene groups produce various handbooks and other collections of data. So if you solution is just a variety of known chemicals you should be able to get some info. For new chemicals, you would be surprised how little info an SDS actually has to contain...

Comment: @JonCuster Yes it's a solution containing well studied chemicals, where could I access these "industrial hygiene group handbooks"? Thank you

Comment: Well, your local IH professional is the best bet. One such group is the American Conference of Governmental Industrial Hygienists who put out things like https://www.techstreet.com/standards/2021-threshold-limit-values-tlvs-and-biological-exposure-indices-beis?product_id=2198547 - a good library may have copies, or can get them through inter-library loan if you don't have an IH professional around.

Comment: @JonCuster I tried this but I couldn't find some of the chemicals I needed. For example Thymol. Most MSDS cites OSHA 2012 standard saying its hazardous but I can't even find Thymol in the OSHA database or any of these hygiene handbooks

Comment: Google a Thymol SDS. I did and got "This chemical is considered hazardous by the 2012 OSHA Hazard Communication Standard (29 CFR 1910.1200)", along with categorization of Acute oral toxicity, and others...

Comment: Yes but how can I find the "This chemical is considered hazardous by the 2012 OSHA Hazard Communication Standard (29 CFR 1910.1200)" reference? As in, where did they get that information in the first place? Got a link?